# Django Authentication Mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb

Hi everyone
I want to use django's built in authentication with mongodb. I have looked online and they aren't really any *stable* and *solid* solutions.

Has anyone mongodb fans out there who can point out to me how this can be achieved with minimal hacking? That would be great.

Comment: this thread should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972480/has-anybody-actually-used-django-mongodb/9306519#9306519

Answer (score 8):

You can't simply use Django built in authentication with MongoDB because [MongoDB is not supported as a back-end for django.db](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/faq.html#how-can-i-use-pymongo-from-a-web-framework-like-django) which is an ORM for Django Authentication. However you may use 3rd modules like **[MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org)** or **[MongoKit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit)** to overcome this problem as they all provide Authentication Module for MongoDB Django apps.

Note: The folks at MongoEngine provide an awesome open source project named **[Mumblr](https://github.com/hmarr/django-mumblr)** which is good to use as a starter for your Django-MongoDB project.

Comment: Hey I looked at their source and they seem to be providing an  external authentication module rather than integrating it with the django's contrib auth. I wanted to use django-registration on top of django-auth which makes the entire registration + authentication. I don't think I can do so with either mongokit or mongoengine because django-registration relies heavily on django.contrib.auth. I was looking more for an answer to make django "integrate" mongodb. I guess I will just 2 separate db for now.

Comment: Yes you get it right. As I said the Django Contrib Auth lib is tied to django.db which is not supported by PyMongo (the driver). Hence we can't just use the native Django Contrib Auth. Moreover, the combination between Django and Non-Relational DBs like MongoDB at this stage is just too 'premature' as we can't have a stable, native supported Authentication feature. Maybe we have to wait for the folks at Django to release this feature. At this stage, we have to find a workaround solution however. I have to rely on **Mumblr** to develop my own CMS. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.)I know somebody tried to do that: Mango(https://github.com/vpulim/mango) and Django-MongoDB(https://bitbucket.org/kpot/django-mongodb/) . Also, checkout this presentation(http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/mongodb-lt3s-django-django-nyc) will give you more insights.