# Using built in Django authentication/User model with Mongodb

Tags: python, django, authentication, mongodb, mongoengine

Switching over from sqlite to MongoDB and I followed all of the setup/configuration settings for [Django MongoDB Engine](http://django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html). Now when I go to add a user by returning an HTTP response from to the adduser method in views.py:

```
 def adduser(request):
     username = request.POST['username']
     password = request.POST['password']
     u = User.objects.create_user(username, request.POST['email'], password)
     u.save()
     a = Accounts(user=u)
     p = Passwords(user=u)
     a.save()
     p.save()
     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
     if user is not None and user.is_active:
         auth.login(request, user)
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s/" %u.id)
     else:
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")
```

This is the error I get:
`DatabaseError at /adduser
relation "auth_user" does not exist`

Naturally the relationship doesn't exist since MongoDB NoSQL. Is the auth system not supported or does Mongo-engine have a better solution? Perhaps I should just move to Postgre? (sqlite cannot handle the simultaneous users so isn't a viable option)

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544473/django-authentication-mongodb) question but that was a year ago so hopefully things have changed by then as MongoDB has gained a lot of popularity this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.5/django.html) provides authentication for Django apps with MongoDB.

Comment: It's just fork of django.contrib.auth, and i can say it's outdated due to use of deprecated hashing password and etc...